# Adding AdMob Interstitial ads in addition to banner ads (IOS)

Tags: ios, admob, interstitial

I have banner ads successfully working in my iOS application, but am struggling adding the code for interstitial ads as I cannot get rid of the error :- "No visible @interface for 'GADInterstitial' declares the selector 'initWithAdUnitId:'".

I am a novice developer and am sure it's a simple mistake I'm making. Can anyone help please ?

My viewcontroller.h looks like this :-

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "GADBannerView.h"
#import "GADRequest.h"
@import GoogleMobileAds;

@class GADBannerView, GADRequest;
@class GADInterstitial, GADRequest;

@interface GenTeamViewController : UIViewController
    <GADBannerViewDelegate, GADInterstitialDelegate> {
    GADBannerView *bannerView_;
    GADInterstitial *interstitialView_;
    NSString *teamName;
    UILabel *teamLabel;
    }


@property(nonatomic, strong) GADInterstitial *interstitial;

@property (nonatomic, strong)GADBannerView *bannerView;
-(GADRequest *)createRequest;
,
,
,
@end
```

The view controller .m looks like :-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.interstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] initWithAdUnitID:@"xxxxxxxxx"];
    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
// Requests test ads on test devices.
    request.testDevices = @[@"xxxxxxxxx"];
    [self.interstitial loadRequest:request];
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your AdMob SDK version is 7.2.1 or newer. The [release notes](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/rel-notes) for 7.2.1 state:

> Added `GADInterstitial initWithAdUnitID:` and deprecated `GADInterstitial
>   init`.

So `initWithAdUnitID:` will not work with AdMob SDK versions older than 7.2.1.

Also, remove `#import "GADBannerView.h"` and `#import "GADRequest.h"` from your header file. You're already importing the entire framework with `@import GoogleMobileAds;`.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, what you say makes sense and I've done as you suggested, but it hasn't got rid of the error - "No visible @interface for 'GADInterstitial' declares the selector 'initWithAdUnitId:'".

Comment: @user1238198 Make sure your AdMob SDK version is 7.2.1 or newer. Read the release notes for 7.2.1 [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/rel-notes)

Comment: AdMob SDK is at 7.2.4 and the 2 header file imports removed, but the No visible @interface error still persists - starting to get more than frustrating now ,,,,,